# Is there a way to scaffold a Web API controller from a Model/Class that is NOT an EntityFramework entity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, scaffolding

I'm using .Net Core 6 and Visual Studio 2022 community edition

VS has these scaffolded item options for WebApi

[image]

The selected option produces CRUD skeleton for `int id, string value` but **If I already have a model and want to scaffold the same CRUD methods using that model, how can I do it ?**

You can assume that my model has this notation to allow the wizard to work with custom model after selecting it

```cs
class Person { 
    [Key]
    string id ;
}
```

```cs
namespace webapi_6
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class EmployeeController : ControllerBase
    {
        // GET: api/<EmployeeController>
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/<EmployeeController>/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/<EmployeeController>
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/<EmployeeController>/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/<EmployeeController>/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I'm aware that I can take the generated code and change it to the type of my model, but that can get boring and easy to make mistakes if I have a few models.

Also I consider that VS should offer this option, since scoffolding should not be limited to entity frameworks.

PD: command line solutions are also welcome

Answer (score 1):

The issue comes down to, Visual Studio can't assume what your model looks like, and how you want to look up items. For instance what property is your index property? It could make assumptions on your behalf but it'd probably be wrong. The entity framework, stores all this information in its metadata, so it's easy to identify this information and to know how to query for said data.

What you could alternatively do. is make a Generic CRUD API controller, adhere your model to an interface, and just create a new Model using said interface.

Example:

```cs
namespace webapi_6
{
    public class GenericController<T> : ControllerBase where T : IMyModel
    {
        protected IStorageAccess<T> storage;
        protected GenericController(IStorageAccess<T> myStorage)
        {
           //Inject some sort of Storage here
           storage = myStorage;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public virtual IEnumerable<T> Get()
        {
            return myStorage.Get();
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public virtual string Get(int id)
        {
            return myStorage.Get(id);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public virtual void Post([FromBody] T value)
        {
        }

        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public virtual void Put(int id, [FromBody] T value)
        {
        }

        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public virtual void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

then you could just implement the generic like so for each of your models, and override methods as needed.

```cs
namespace webapi_6
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class EmployeeController : GenericController<Employee>
    {
        public EmployeeController(IStorageAccess<Employee> myStorage) : base(myStorage)
    }
}
```

Alternatively there might be a 3rd party plugin, I've not come across one, but it wouldn't be far-fetched to make a Visual Studio Plugin that would do exactly this. You could probably start with a T4 template even. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-and-t4-text-templates

Comment: Selecting the model would be something that the wizard would require, so VS would not have to guess/assume. The `[Key]` attribute could be used on that model to indicate which property to use when lookup is done. Thanks for showing me the repository pattern but is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: I have updated my question to make it a bit more clear

Comment: I've not come across one, but it wouldn't be far-fetched to make a Visual Studio Plugin that would do exactly this. You could probably start with a T4 template even.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-and-t4-text-templates?view=vs-2022

Comment: Thanks, yes custom template would probably sove this, thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of Visual Studio 2022, there is the possibility to scaffold Web API endpoints based on defined models and create an MSSQL local database without manually creating migrations and typing commands for adding and updating the database.

Create an API project using the latest .NET version and the default settings. Then, create a Models folder that contains only one entity.

When the model is successfully created, the scaffolding technique can create CRUD actions.

During scaffolding, required NuGets are added to the solution, and after scaffolding is done, there will be YourEntityEndpoints.cs, where API calls are located, and in the Data folder FastMinimalAPIContext.cs will be located. Also, in Program.cs, Entity framework configuration will be added automatically.

Answer (score -1):

Create a Model/Class:

First, create a class or model that represents the data you want to expose through your Web API. This class does not need to be an Entity Framework entity.
Add a Controller:

Right-click on the Controllers folder in your project.
Select "Add" -> "Controller...".
In the "Add Scaffold" dialog, choose "API" on the left.
Select "API Controller with actions, using Entity Framework" (even though you are not using Entity Framework).
Configure the Scaffolding:

In the "Model class" dropdown, select your custom model or class (e.g., YourModel).
In the "Data context class" dropdown, leave it as "Use a separate data context class" (since you are not using Entity Framework).
Click "Add."
Review and Modify Generated Code:

Visual Studio will generate a controller with basic CRUD actions in the Controllers folder.
Open the generated controller file (e.g., YourModelsController.cs) and review the code.
Note: You may need to adjust the code if you are not using Entity Framework for data access. The default scaffolding assumes Entity Framework, so you might need to replace the data access code with your own logic.

Customize the Controller Actions:

Customize the controller actions according to your data access needs. You can replace the default Entity Framework-based code with your own logic to interact with the data source.